# visa entry date later then CoS working date

Tags: uk-visa, skilled-migration

What if my approved valid date (the date I am allowed to enter The UK) on skilled working visa (UK)is 2 months later than the working date on CoS(certification of sponsorship)?

The value date on working visa is in November (I filled a wrong date on my application form), but my CoS work start date is in August.

28 days rule (I don’t really understand this rule)

“CAN WORK START DATE BE DELAYED AFTER SKILLED WORKER VISA IS GRANTED

Once the Skilled Worker visa is granted, the work start date must not be delayed by more than 28 days from whichever is the latest of:

the start date recorded on the worker's CoS (including any amendment to that date you have told us about via SMS while the worker was awaiting a decision on their application)
the date the worker's entry clearance (visa) becomes valid
the date the worker is granted permission to enter or permission to stay
WHAT HAPPENS IF WORK START DATE IS DELAYED FOR MORE THAN 28 DAYS FOR SKILLED WORKER

If the work start date is delayed by more than 28 days, the sponsor employer must normally stop sponsoring the worker and inform the Home Office via Sponsor Management System (SMS) account accordingly.“

Comment: CoS?  What is that?  I suppose if I recognized it, I would know what country you're asking about, but I don't, so I don't.  What country is it?

Comment: @phoog Looks like a Certificate of Sponsorship for one of the UK work visas to me. But I agree, the OP should edit that information into the question.

Comment: By *value date* do you mean *start date*, ie the date you’ll be able to enter the UK?

Comment: Yes, the effective date is the date I will be able to enter the UK. Now, because I made the mistake of not being able to enter the UK before my job start date. I have called the Home Office to change the visa date and they say it would take 15 working days to review the situation. Then 15 days later I called them again and they said they need another 15 days. My concern is whether they can really help me change the date of entry into the UK? And there is a 28 days rule. I am not really understand which date it means (after the valid date on visa or work start date on CoS)

Comment: @LamChorMei What did your employer say when you asked them?

Comment: They just help me to call the home office to see if they can change the date. So what they can do also just wait till home office give us their answer. This Friday is the 15th working day, hope they can change the date for me.